# Extract class name in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, css-selectors, scrapy

I am trying to scrape rating off of trustpilot.com.

Is it possible to extract a class name using scrapy? I am trying to scrape a rating which is made up of five individual images but the images are in a class with the name of the rating for example if the rating is 2 starts then:

```
<div class="star-rating count-2 size-medium clearfix">...
```

if it is 3 stars then:

```
<div class="star-rating count-3 size-medium clearfix">...
```

So is there a way I can scrape the class `count-2` or `count-3` assuming a selector like `.css('.star-rating')`?

Comment: You could combine it with an xpath like `response.css('.star-rating').xpath("@class").extract()` (not tested).

Comment: Thanks, that returns `['star-rating count-4 size-medium clearfix']` which is close enough to get something working. But do you know if I can use xpath to only get the classes starting with `count-`?

Comment: You could try: `response.css('.star-rating').xpath(".//[contains(@class, 'count-')]/@class").extract()`

Comment: That errored, but this sort of hack works `response.css('.star-rating').xpath('./@class').extract()[0].split(' ')[1][-1]`

Comment: Otherwise please give a demo link.

Comment: Dan I'm fairly certain that xpath1 only operates on nodes in the dom.  scrapy uses lxml which only implements xpath1.  xpath2 has some nifty functions like matches, tokenize, and replace that you could use to directly get what you want.  Otherwise Jan's answer is the best you will get

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a combination of both somewhere in your code:

```
import re

classes = response.css('.star-rating').xpath("@class").extract()
for cls in classes:
    match = re.search(r'\bcount-\d+\b', cls)
    if match:
        print("Class = {}".format(match.group(0))
```

Comment: Thanks, ended up combining the two answers to `response.css('.star-rating').xpath("@class").re(r'count-(\d)')[0]`

Answer (score 4):

You can extract rating directly using `re_first()` and `re()`:

```
for rating in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "star-rating")]/@class').re(r'count-(\d+)'):
    print(rating)
```

Comment: Thanks, ended up combining the two answers to `response.css('.star-rating').xpath("@class").re(r'count-(\d)')[0]`

Comment: @Dan You'll get an exception on pages without rating (`[0]` will not work for `None`)

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like 1 star is the lowest allowed.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar question.  Using scrapy v1.5.1 I could extract attributes of elements by name. Here is an example used on Lowes; I did the same with the `class` attribute

```
    for product in response.css('ul.product-cards-grid li.product-wrapper'):
        prod_href = p.css('li::attr(data-producturl)').extract()
        prod_name = p.css('li::attr(data-producttitle)').extract_first()
        prod_img  = p.css('li::attr(data-productimg)').extract_first()
        prod_id   = p.css('li::attr(data-productid)').extract_first()
```