# Scraping class name of image Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape review details from tripadvisor.com but for it to be worth something, I need to be able to retrieve the ratings as well. However, they are given in images instead of actual numbers. The image have distinct class names for instance a 5 star rating image has the following code `class="ui_bubble_rating.bubble_50` and a 1 star rating has the following: `class="ui_bubble_rating.bubble_10"`.

I have been able to retrieve the following:

```
In [19]: response.css('div.location-review-review-list-parts-RatingLine__bubbles--GcJvM > span').extract_first()                                                                                            
Out[19]: '<span class="ui_bubble_rating.bubble_40"></span>'
```

However, I would like to only retrieve `ui_bubble_rating.bubble_40` as it would make the process easier.

Is there a way that I can scrape the class name so that I can retrieve the rating?

I have been trying it at with the following hotel but it could be any:
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g188590-d6767297-Reviews-or15-XO_Hotels_Couture-Amsterdam_North_Holland_Province.html

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: @Sri I have added it to the message itself, thanks!

Comment: So you can get the tag with the data. There are several ways to proceed. You could  directly parse the string after class=" and before the closing ". You could also do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692446/extract-class-name-in-scrapy