# How to web scrape based on start of class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, cheerio

How can I find all elements with class name starting with a certain string?

I know Cheerio can do things like `$(".item")` to get things with that exact class name. And I know you can do `$("*:contains('hello')")` to get all elements that has that string in the content.

But how do I filter based on part of the class name?

My first thought is to just scrape all the "divs" and apply a filter function afterwards, but that seems inefficient (or not? Is that what it would be doing anyway?) I'm looking for something like `$("div:classStartsWith('ItemBox_')")`

I looked at this question [Extract class name in scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692446/extract-class-name-in-scrapy) and it seems you can do it in python with `response.css('.star-rating').xpath("@class").extract()` . What is the equivalent of that in javascript and cheerio?

Comment: The CSS selector would be `"div[class~=ItemBox_]"` - if you really want "starts with" rather than "contains", use `"div[class^=ItemBox_]"`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors